# function is not defined at file://android_asset/www/index.html in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I get this typical error on Phonegap 
I call a function on button onclick event,  but I get (function_name) is not defined at file://android_asset/www/index.html in phonegap. Then, i write the code temp on some other page, it starts working. Again after some time the same error comesback.
I can't figure out what's wrong.
I am working with phonegap - Android (on eclipse)
Any help would be appreciated.

```
  <button onclick="clickIt();" data-theme="b">Login</button>

   <script type="text/javascript">

        function clickIt() {
           //code here

        }
   </script>
```

Comment: Add a click listener `('button')on('click',function () { alert('clicked') });` instead of inline function. Remove `onclick=clickit`.

Comment: Even the click listener is not working. I even tried adding the following code:                                                  <div id="target">Click here</div>            $("#target").click(function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
  }); None of the click events or click listeners are working on any of the tags(p,div,a,button)

Comment: ok try this instead of `<button>`, `<a href="#" data-role="button" id="test">test</a>` and function `$('#test').on('click', function () { alert('clicked'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Actually i had an error at some function in my file and so no java script call was functioning. It was an error that was not found and caused other code to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem too. Unfortunately the Android emulator is REALLY slow
so a timeout occurs while loading the files because it reacts to slow.

Within your custom Activity file before calling super.loadUrl add the
following line:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

This increases the timeout for loading the webpage - this fixed the
issue for me on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call the function only after the js file is initiated. You can make sure by callilng it inside `$(document).on` function. first change the id of the button to `login` and do as below.

Something as below

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', function(){
    $('#login').bind('click',function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

If you have a page id equals to “mypage” change it to something as below

```
$(document).on('pagecreate',  '#mypage', function(){
    $('#login').bind('click',function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

Check out the live fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/9pNRn/

Comment: I tried your code. Now I feel that javascript is not being called at all. None of the function calls are working. Is it some kind of phonegap specific error?

Comment: no no phonegap do supports functions. it should work. avoid writing inline javascripts.